# mlflow: saving signature gives me warning

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, metadata, mlflow

I am using mlflow with sqlite backend. started the server with:

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlruns_db/mlruns.db --default-artifact-root $PWD/mlruns --host 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
```

in the code, I log the model with signature as such

```
...
signature = infer_signature(X, y)
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(model, model_name, signature=signature)
...
```

then I get warnings

> 2022/05/26 19:52:17 WARNING mlflow.models.model: Logging model metadata to the tracking server has failed, possibly due older server version. The model artifacts have been logged successfully under ./mlruns/1/d4c8f611d3f24986a32d19c7d8b03f06/artifacts. In addition to exporting model artifacts, MLflow clients 1.7.0 and above attempt to record model metadata to the tracking store. If logging to a mlflow server via REST, consider upgrading the server version to MLflow 1.7.0 or above.

I am using `mlflow, version 1.24.0`, though.

I see that the signature is correctly logged inside `MLmodel` file, but the nice rendering of mlflow ui is lost.

1. with logging signature
   [mlflow ui with logging signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2FwI.png)
2. without logging signature
   [mlflow ui without logging signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nQ8w.png)

Does this have any consequence later when serving models with signature enforcement?
Also, I see many blog examples with postgres instead of sqlite, and sftp/minio instead of filestore. maybe changing to those setups will solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Even after running both server and local on 1.30

you can import this:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("mlflow").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

The logging told me it was because the size of the paramaters exceeded the character limit of 5000. This was because my model signature was about 10k in length.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to increase the character limit? Or some other way to fix this?